# Can I easily "set" an element's offsetWidth?

Tags: javascript, width, dhtml

*Note: I know offsetWidth is read only*

I'm trying to make a pop-up 'div' overlay a `tr` element with the exact same width.

However, I am stumped as to how to set my `div`'s `width` so that its `offsetWidth` is the exact same as the `tr`.

The calculation would look something like:

```
div.width = tr.offsetWidth - div.paddingWidth - div.marginWidth
```

but surely there's a better way (since I can only think of getting the padding and margin offsets in groups of two...)

Specifically, I'd like an answer for YUI 2 if possible.

Comment: It looks to me like you've answered your own question. My only recommendation would be to get the div's computed left and right margin and padding values separately, since they could all be different.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Ok, so I've changed the title to _easily_ setting the width. I just have trouble believing it's not built in to some library somewhere (even if it's not YUI)

Comment: Also note that computed styles etc may return values like '40px' which is less than useful for arithmetic

Comment: You'll have to access margin and padding information through the element's style, e.g. `div.style.paddingLeft`. Remember it has a unit, so if it's not in pixels you're out of luck. If it is then you'll have to parse out the number part first for your calculation to work, which is why I prefer having everything zero'd out as described in my answer. (You *may* be able to get some better normalized margin and padding information through the `window.getComputedStyle` method but I have no idea of browser support for it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you zero out your `div`'s margin and paddings then something like the following should work:

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(div, 'width', tr.offsetWidth + 'px');
```

Depending on how you are dealing with borders on your `div` and `tr` you may want to assign `tr.clientWidth` instead.

You can then set any margin/paddings as required on the parent/child elements of your `div` to achieve the desired appearance.

The key to working out what you'll want to do is understanding exactly what [`clientWidth` and `offsetWidth` measure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements), and that the CSS `width` of an element is its content area and excludes any margin, border, and padding defined on it ([see the W3C box model here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aW3C_and_Internet_Explorer_box_models.svg)).

You could include the padding etc. in your calculation by querying it from the

Comment: Currently, my div has an error class attached to it which sets the background color, image and respective padding. Am I correct in thinking I can still set the width on the parent div, and then embedding the error with width at 100%?

Comment: A block level element like a `div` by default will occupy the width of its parent container so there shouldn't be any need to set its width IIRC.

Comment: New container div created and zero'd with correct width, and the formatted original/child div fills container and has all it's own lovely padding etc. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a little messy and I may get downvoted for suggesting it, but one way you could do this without messing with your margin or padding is to set the div's width to a known value, then finding the difference between that and the div's offsetWidth. That should tell you what to set the width to in order to make it fit.

```
div.style.width = '20px'
diff = div.offsetWidth - 20;
div.style.width = tr.offsetWidth - diff;
```

It is really messy but you don't have to care about the padding, margin or border this way.

Comment: Is it no the case that setting the width could cause the layout engine to reflow the layout on the page. When you set the width a second time, it might reflow a second time.  So yes, that is very messy.